# Show different message to logged in and non logged in users on particular post type wordpress

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

I have a question-answer plugin installed so the post type is example.com/question/
I want to show the message just below the post content
it should say "Login or Register" to **non logged in** users
and welcome to logged-in users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code to your theme where applicable:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Welcome ' . esc_html($current_user->display_name);
} else {
    // Save current page url for redirect after login (optional):
    global $wp;
    $redirect = home_url($wp->request);

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url(wp_login_url($redirect)) . '">Login or Register</a>';
}
```

Also: WordPress has a native function for that - `wp_loginout()`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_loginout/
It won't show the welcome message off the box, but will give logged in users the option to log out instead.

Answer (score 1):

### You're looking for [`is_user_logged_in();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)

> Determines whether the current visitor is a logged in user.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

```
<?php

if ( 'question' === get_post_type() ) {

  if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

    echo 'An account is required.';
  
  } else {
  
    // ...
  
  };

};
```